# Installing Stock ROM in a low end spread trum device

Tags: android, android-2.3-gingerbread, fastboot

I have a low end device i.e Micromax a27 which I m trying to restore after I had rooted it and tried to free up some space by removing the apps which broke the phone's OS.

Mistakenly I also executed a command in fastboot mode that flashed the system with a recovery.img(`fastboot flash system recovery.img`) after which the phone keeps on buzzing infinitely and nothing shows up on the screen.

I then tried to follow this method http://androidxda.com/flash-pac-stock-rom-android-smartphone but the phone starts buzzing endlessly when plugged in with a USB cable and nothing is shown in the status panel of tool mentioned in it (UpgradeDownload.exe)

This tool seems to extract the .img files from the .pac package(present under the firmware folder of the downloaded stock ROM) and place it in the phone,Can I somehow extract them from .pac and place them manually in the phone via fastboot?

Please suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First yes you can use `ADB` the Android Debugging Bridge to `push` and `pull` files to & from Android with a PC; it takes a bit of setup but is possible as a last resort... though I've a few tips...

---

Few tips on Android debugging and support;

Google is great

- `<device> <issue/task> site:<someusefull-site>.<domain>`

The above is how I usually resurch issues as well as learn new things that others have done.

The search I used for your device

- `unbrick micromax a27 similar:xda`

Note: I didn't have to suply a full web address because `similar:<something>` in Google will search related sites ;-)

Few tips for flashing Android;

- Use a differant USB port &/or cable to re-flash; this one thing can make or fix a brick quick.
- Re-download all recovery files and check if they differ in size or hashsum to the ones previously downloaded; this catches errors that may have been introduced durring your first or second download. Compare these file sizes and hashes to the ones that should be listed on the pages your downloads are hosted from.

---

Result I found :

- [A blog with directions](http://lusarap.blogspot.com/2014/09/how-to-hard-or-soft-unbrick-micromax.html) for your device and one other
- [Where to download](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2520719) sources for even more veriants of your device

I can only post two links at a time but from the fifteen that I read through on your device these are the most comprehencive.
Basicly if you can get into download/recovery mode, usually volume down with power button held from a cold boot, then it is posible to recover without a PC if you still have a good backup or known working ROM to flash; else you'll have to power on a PC and trust some software to reflash your device and still be in download mode.

If you can't get into download mode then without special hardware you maybe the unfortunet winner of a very expencive brick. But be sure to do a little reading because my old HTC would turn into a vibrator when flashed with a bad USB cable but would easily recover once I use a differant one. Perma bricks are rare, so rare I've yet to experiance one, but are usually caused by flashing the wrong image or radio or removing parts of the kernal.

Comment: thanks but I had tried most of these things here and I am unable to run the ADB as phone just doesnt starts but buzzes endlessly when Powered On and I do not know why :D :D
Only option which seems to be working is the Fastboot and I am trying to use it

Comment: If you can get into fastboot and have an external SD card try re-downloading the files to the SD card with another device; PC with adapter or another Android. Then place the SD card back in and try flashing with fastboot. The fact that it still gets into fastboot means that it's not perma bricked :-) and you can recover. Oh just be sure to pop the battery before pulling the SD card as well as properly un-mounting it from the secondery device that was used to re download the files. And by fastboot you meen that your able to select things to flash? If you see a triangle that's download mode.

Comment: why to use a SD card for files when I can directly transfer them from my laptop?I tried sending system.img and recovery.img to the respected partitions and every time they succeeded but when I turn on the phone again it starts buzzing endlessly(funny) :D

Comment: Ah in that case it is the USB port, charging port, and/or cable that you are using. Other options is the flashing software or drivers or another task trying to also assosiate with the device when plugged in. I would first try another cable in a different port, then if that doesn't work try re-installing drivers and flashing software. Also try closing any other task that maybe operating when flashing that is not required; web browser included. Flashing from SD card kinda cuts a lot of veriables out of the equasion so that is why I suggest it as the better cource of action.